# Linking within jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Suppose we have 2 separate jqGrid pages. On one side we have an overview about artists, on the other an overview about their works. I done linking with context menu. For example, from artist there is a link to their works. The link is as follows

```
$(window.location).attr('href', $(window.location).attr('href').replace('c_picture','c_edition')+'?_search=true&rows=10&page=1&searchField=work_id&searchOper=eq&searchString='+jQuery("#grid").getCell(e.id, 'work_id');
```

Is it a reasonable solution to the problem?

PS. I am not looking for ajax load, I try to make a link to another page (to another grid). I changed my call now to `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace('c_picture','c_edition')+'/?_search=true&rows=10&page=1&searchField=work_id&searchOper=eq&searchString='+jQuery('#grid').getCell(e.id, 'work_id');` But this method seems still to be very "dirty". For example with window.location.href I can not change parameter `_search`. Is it better to make small form with all GET-Parameters and then submit this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I link two grids together on a single page (not sure if that's what you're talking about here) as follows

by using the onSelectRow to set the url on the grid to be 'affected'..

jQuery("#userGrid").jqGrid({
   "datatype":"json",
   "rowNum":10,
   ...

...
   'onSelectRow':function(id, status) { 
      jQuery('#userDetailsGrid').setGridParam({
         url:'jsonRequest.php?JSONRequestType=details&userId='+id,
         page:1
      })
      .trigger('reloadGrid');
   },
   ...

...
};

Note: looks like $(window.location).attr('href') is something you should avoid generally as it's broken in 1.4.3 and 1.4.4 - see http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7607

Comment: Dave, thanks for your hint and for information about bug. I changed my call now - see above.